# Fourier Mukai kernel of identity for equivariant derived category

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

Suppose $X$ is an smooth projective variety with a finite group $G$ action. I am trying to see that the FM kernel of the identity morphism of  $D^b_G(X)$ is $\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_X} \otimes \mathbb{C}[G]$ where $\Delta_X$ is the diagonal and $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is the regular representation.

I have verified this in some easy examples, what I would like to know is:

1.Do I have the correct kernel?

2.If yes for 1, what is the motivation for tensoring with the regular representation?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the action of $G$ on $X$ is non-trivial, then the kernel that you describe is not $G\times G$-equivariant. The kernel should be $\bigoplus_g O_{\Gamma_g}$, where $\Gamma_g\subset X\times X$ is the graph of action of $g$ (or, more canonically, it is the direct image of $O$ under the action map $G\times X\to X\times X$).